# Update cache stored via HTTP2 requests

Tags: node.js, browser-cache, http2

Normally, I would serve files via http2 requests like this:

```
if (req.url === '/main.html') {
  let files = {
    'main.css': {
      type: 'text/css'
    },
    'main.js': {
      type: 'application/javascript'
    }
  };
  for (let name in files) {
    let push = res.push('/' + name, {
      response: {
        'Content-Type': files[name].type,
        'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=31556926'
      }
    });
    push.on('error', er => console.log(er));
    push.end(fs.readFileSync('/home/src/' + name));
  }
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
  });
  res.end(`
   <html>
     <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
       <script src="/main.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body></body>
   </html>
`);
}
```

I got a problem with updating those 2 files `main.css` and `main.js` when their new contents are available.
Will they be updated just by sending another `/main.html` request? If not, how can I update them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they won't get updated. When you try to push new versions of the assets, the browser will reset the streams because it considers that those assets are still fresh. And it will continue using the old version of the assets.

For now at least, the solution is to use a cache digest mechanism *and* cache busting.

Read the details here:

https://www.shimmercat.com/en/info/articles/caching/

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200074/is-it-necessary-to-cache-bust-in-http-2/37202091#37202091).

Comment: Big thanks for your answer. I also thinking about setting a very short lifetime via `max-age` to remove the old caches. Have you ever try this method? Does it work in all browsers?

Comment: Hi! Yes, this method works well in Internet Explorer, Chrome and Firefox. Safari doesn't support HTTP/2 Push, so there is no need for it there.